# How to read deadletter count from service bus topic and its subscription in c# using .NET SDK for Azure Service Bus?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-monitoring

Azure Monitor provides many metrics for Service Bus such as “Incoming, Outgoing, Active” Messages
[Service bus Matrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/monitor-service-bus-reference) giving you the total message count and when trying to look into the details of that metric “DeadletteredMessages”, I can get counts by the “EntityName” which is either a queue or a topic but not the subscription-level metrics.

I was facing challenges while getting all the dead-letter and other messages count from the topic and its subscriptions.
I have spent almost 4-5 hrs to resolve the above issue.

I hope, below answer might be a help to Monitor service Bus

Answer (score 6):

```
Here is the sample code for the same.

[FunctionName("ServiceBusMonitor")]
        public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient(_configuration.GetValue<string>("ServiceBusConnectionString"));
                var topics = client.GetTopicsAsync()?.GetAsyncEnumerator();
                while (await topics.MoveNextAsync())
                {
                    TopicProperties topicProperties = topics.Current;
                    var subscriptions = client.GetSubscriptionsAsync(topicProperties.Name)?.GetAsyncEnumerator();
                    log.LogInformation($"{topicProperties.Name}");

                    var subscriptionRuntimePropertiesAsync = client.GetSubscriptionsRuntimePropertiesAsync(topicProperties.Name)?.GetAsyncEnumerator();
                    while (await subscriptionRuntimePropertiesAsync.MoveNextAsync())
                    {
                        var subscriptionRuntimeProperties = subscriptionRuntimePropertiesAsync.Current;
                        Console.WriteLine($"Topic Name {subscriptionRuntimeProperties.TopicName}, Subscription Name {subscriptionRuntimeProperties.SubscriptionName}");
                        Console.WriteLine($"DeadLetterMessageCount : {subscriptionRuntimeProperties.DeadLetterMessageCount} ActiveMessageCount : {subscriptionRuntimeProperties.ActiveMessageCount} TotalMessageCount : {subscriptionRuntimeProperties.TotalMessageCount} " );
//You can log subscriptionRuntimeProperties in Application insight and use the for the monitor
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------");
                }

                log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now} {ex.Message}");

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Talking only about monitoring Service Bus there is a great tool out there called [Service Bus Explorer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer):

> The Service Bus Explorer allows users to efficiently administer messaging entities. The tool provides advanced features like import/export functionality and the ability to test topic, queues, subscriptions, relay services, notification hubs and events hubs.

Some of this tool's functionality is also available (in preview) [via the Azure Portal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/sesrvice-bus-explorer/) when you select a specific Queue or Topic:

> The Service Bus Explorer tool on the Azure portal is now available in
> preview.
>
> Azure Service Bus, like most other PaaS offerings, has two sets of
> operations that can be performed against it:
>
> Management operations like CRUD (create, read, update, and delete) on Service Bus namespaces, queues, topics, subscriptions, and filters.
> Data operations like send, receive, and peek on queues, topics, and subscriptions.

Both approaches will let you manually keep track of your topics and queues.